# I am facing this error while started evaluation/training: _3d_result = torch.load(path[0])[0] KeyError: 0

Tags: numpy, pytorch, 3d, keyerror

I am facing error in this piece of code:
for fusion_input,tensor_index,path in tqdm(val_data)  
fusion_input = fusion_input.cuda()  
tensor_index = tensor_index.reshape(-1,2)  
tensor_index = tensor_index.cuda()  
_3d_result = torch.load(path[0])[0]  
fusion_cls_preds,flag = net(fusion_input,tensor_index)
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daxla.png)
I am trying to evaluate/train the CLOC Fusion Network in the repository of PointPillars-Camera-LiDAR-Fusion, but facing the same error during evaluating/training:  adeel@adeel-ubuntu:~/PointPillars-Camera-LiDAR-Fusion/CLOC_fusion$ sudo python3 eval.py/train.py.
[1st page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOZec.png)
[last page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXDhF.png)